# Oracle Apex Add IF Statement to set a value in a form

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am working on a system in Oracle Apex 22.1 where there is a Form, where the user enters an amount of money to be validated by the company. There are 3 fields which are a select list `P3_REQUEST_TYPE`, a text field `P3_AMOUNT` and a select list `P3_TYPE_CURRENCY`. What I want to do is that if the user selects the option "`Payment Request`" in `P3_REQUEST_TYPE`, and according to the amount entered in `P3_AMOUNT` and the type of currency in `P3_TYPE_CURRENCY` (USD, JPY), put the value "1" in the field `P3_FG_RT` for validation reasons.

I would like to know if there is a way to do it through a IF function since through dynamic actions I have not been able to make it work, I would greatly appreciate your help.

The amounts for the "1" to be placed are: if it is greater than or equal to 5,000 and they are USD, or if it is greater than or equal to 18,000 and they are JPY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like dynamic action, indeed.

- its action would be "Set value"
- type might be PL/SQL Function body:

  ```
  RETURN CASE WHEN    :P3_REQUEST_TYPE = 'Payment Request'
                  AND :P3_TYPE_CURRENCY IN ('USD', 'JPY')
             THEN 1
         END;
  ```
- items to submit: `P3_REQUEST_TYPE`, `P3_TYPE_CURRENCY`
- affected elements: item, `P3_FG_RT`

Though, as you said that these are Select List items, I kind of doubt that **return values** really are "Payment Request" or "JPY" - I presume that you actually return their *codes*, not *descriptions* so `CASE` expression might need to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The decision to use a dynamic action depends on the following question: *is the value that needs to be set of importance before the page is submitted or does it only matter at submit time*
@Littefoot explained how to do the dynamic action but if this value is only needed after the page is submitted, it is easier to set the value of page item `P3_FG_RT`  with a a computation (process point *After Submit*).

One way to implement this computation is:

- Type: Static Value
- Static Value: 1
- Server Side Condition: Expression
- PL/SQL Expression:

```
:P3_REQUEST_TYPE = 'Payment Request' AND :P3_TYPE_CURRENCY IN ('USD', 'JPY')
```